# How to generate Dynaminc Side menu using Cordova and wcf resf ful api

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, wcf

I am facing a trouble related to generating dynamic side nav menu. I m having side nav like this in `html` page

```
<div id="s_m">
  <li> <a href="gr.html">Gr</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="di.html">Di</a> </li>
  <li> <a href="ho.html"></i>Ho</a> </li>
</div>
```

And script page:

```
function dynmnu() {
    var se = Session.getInstance().get();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: Txxxxxx.Sxxxxxx.gxxxxxxr,
        data: "Lxxxxx_=" + sxx.uxxxxd + "",
        success: function(resp) {
            //alert(resp);
            document.getElementById('dyna_menu').innerHTML = "<div>" + resp + "</div>"
        },
        error: function(e) {
            navigator.notification.alert(e.error);
        }
    });
}
```

Created a rest full API like this

```
 public string Page()
    {
        string page_ = "";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_master";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                ["Name"], Sp_details = dt.Rows[i]["Sp_details"], Html_Links=dt.Rows[i]["Html_Links"] ,status = dt.Rows[i]["status"] });

                page_ = page_ + "<li><a onclick='menu(" + dt.Rows[i]["Sp_details"] + ")'>" + dt.Rows[i]["ReportName"] + "</a></li>";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return page_;
    }
```

and here is the sql server db design

### sno   Name        Sp_details        Html_Links           status

### 1      Ca             sp_Ca                 ca.html                 1

2     Gr          sp_Da             gr.html                1

here now im getting the side nav where i am stuck is i unable perform onclick event and it is not firing and im getting the below error  "Uncaught ReferenceError: dis is not defined".

Comment: First of all let us know if what is the response `resp` of your ajax call ? And then where is `dis` word is used in your code ?

Comment: the resp i am getting is  side nav names it is displayed on the menu but onclick i unable to perform and here " dis" is just one of the side nav content name